# OpenGl mapping a texture perpendicular to an edge in 2D

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, texture-mapping, texture2d

Using libgdx i'm trying to build a 2d ground with a surface on top of it. For that surface i need to map a texture perpendicularly to the top edges. (The ground is made of points at random altitudes, and an edge is a connection between 2 ground points).

Here the illustration of the problem :

[image: flat vs perpendicular]

I guess i must somehow offset the coordinates values of my vertices... But what is the geometry trick behind that ?

Simplified code :

```
private Texture _theSurfaceTexture ;
private ShaderProgram _theShader ;
private Mesh _theSurfaceMesh ;

private Array<Vector2> _aPoints ;

public GroundRenderer(){

    _theSurfaceTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture_surface_4.png"));
    _theSurfaceTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
    _theSurfaceTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    String vert = Gdx.files.internal("data/shader/VertexShaderGround.txt").readString();
    String frag = Gdx.files.internal("data/shader/FragmentShaderGround.txt").readString();

    _theShader = new ShaderProgram(vert, frag);

    _aPoints = new Array<Vector2>();
    _aPoints.add(new Vector2(50, 150));
    _aPoints.add(new Vector2(100, 50));
    _aPoints.add(new Vector2(300, 250));
    _aPoints.add(new Vector2(400, 100));

    int nbPoints = _aPoints.size ;
    int nbVertices = nbPoints * 2 ;
    int nbFloats = nbVertices * 4 ;

    _theSurfaceMesh = new Mesh(Mesh.VertexDataType.VertexArray, false, nbVertices, nbFloats,
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"),
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoord0"));


}

private void buildTheMesh(Array<Vector2>aPoints){

    int nbPoints = aPoints.size ;
    int nbVertices = nbPoints * 2 ;
    int nbFloats = nbVertices*4 ;

    int nbTriangles = nbPoints/2 ;
    int nbIndices = nbTriangles*3 ;

    float[] verts = new float[nbFloats];
    short[] indices = new short[nbIndices];

    float texW ;
    texW = (float) _theSurfaceTexture.getWidth() ;

    Vector2 p1, p2, p3, p4 ;
    float x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 ;

    // POINTS

    // top left
    p1 = aPoints.get(0);
    x1 = (float)p1.x ;
    y1 = (float)p1.y ;

    // bottom left
    p2 = aPoints.get(1);
    x2 = (float)p2.x ;
    y2 = (float)p2.y ;

    // top right
    p3 = aPoints.get(2);
    x3 = (float)p3.x ;
    y3 = (float)p3.y ;

    // bottom right
    p4 = aPoints.get(3);
    x4 = (float)p4.x ;
    y4 = (float)p4.y ;


    // TRIANGLE LEFT

    // top left
    verts[0] = x1 ;  // position x
    verts[1] = y1 ;  // position y
    verts[2] = x1 / texW ; // coordinate  
    verts[3] = 0 ; // coordinate

    // bottom left
    verts[4] = x2 ; 
    verts[5] = y2 ; 
    verts[6] = x2 / texW ;
    verts[7] = 1 ; 

    // top right
    verts[8] = x3 ; 
    verts[9] = y3 ; 
    verts[10] = x3 / texW ; 
    verts[11] = 0 ; 


    // TRIANGLE RIGHT

    // top right
    verts[12] = x3 ; 
    verts[13] = y3 ; 
    verts[14] = x3 / texW ; 
    verts[15] = 0 ; 

    // bottom right
    verts[16] = x4 ; 
    verts[17] = y4 ; 
    verts[18] = x4 / texW ; 
    verts[19] = 1 ; 

    // bottom left
    verts[20] = x2 ; 
    verts[21] = y2 ; 
    verts[22] = x2 / texW ;
    verts[23] = 1 ; 


    // INDICES

    indices[0] = (short)(1) ;
    indices[1] = (short)(0) ;
    indices[2] = (short)(2) ;

    indices[3] = (short)(4) ;
    indices[4] = (short)(5) ;
    indices[5] = (short)(3) ;

    _theSurfaceMesh.setVertices(verts);
    _theSurfaceMesh.setIndices(indices) ;

}

public void render(){

    buildTheMesh(_aPoints);

    Game.BATCH.setShader(_theShader);

    _theShader.begin();

    _theSurfaceTexture.bind(0);
    _theShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    _theShader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", Game.CAMERA_ORTHO.combined);
    _theSurfaceMesh.render(_theShader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);

    _theShader.end();


}
```

Shader vertex :

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {         
 v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
 gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position; 
}
```

Shader fragment :

```
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

Comment: I *think* you simply want to transform your texture coordinates in a coordinate space which has basis (V0, V1), with V0=P3-P1 and a V1 being a vector orthogonal to V0 in screen space (in the same halfplane of P2, I guess). In other words: apply Gram-Schmidt to P3-P1 and P2-P1 and use texture coordinates in that space.

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks promising. Have you any idea how i should best implement that in the code ? In the shaders ? Or in the main code by modifying the vertex coordinates ? (e.g. verts[6] = (x2 + someSpecialGramSchmidtValue) / texW instead of current verts[6] = x2 / texW)